# Any advice on good breweries near São Paulo - Brazil?

Tags: breweries, local, ipa, ale

I am moving back home in the next few days and the idea of importing all my beer does not seem reasonable.

I'm willing to try any kind of beer, but my preference is for IPA's and Belgian Strong pale ales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

São Paulo has seen a big rise in the craft beer scene through the last years (as does the whole country), so you'll probably find what you're looking for. The city doesn't have an actual (physical) brewery of its own (besides brewpubs, which are only a few, the most relevant being Cervejaria Nacional), once most of them are in the countryside of São Paulo state.
Anyway, you won't be disappointed with beers available and bar options - Pinheiros region being the place where you'll find the best ones.
Keep an eye open for Jupiter, Urbana, STP, which are gypsy breweries born in the city, and have a lot of modern styles (Black IPAs, American Wheat, Brown IPAs, APAs, etc). Urbana has a very good Belgian Strong Golden Ale called Gordelícia, by the way.
Bamberg is a brewery dedicated to german styles, with some state-of-art german style reproductions with tons of international awards. Colorado is one of the oldest breweries in the country and, although it doesn't have a wide portfolio, its beers are easy to find at supermarkets, affordable and still very good. They have a very good english-american-hybrid IPA with 'rapadura' (a candy made of molasses). Invicta is one of my favorites from here, having from humble Weizenbiers to Imperial American IPAs, all very good.
Don't miss Empório Alto dos Pinheiros (EAP), the best craft-beer bar in the city, with 30+ taps and excellent food at a fair price. Ah, well, prices overall here aren't very good. Actually, even though the whole craft beer scene is growing faster and faster, taxes and other aspects of the market aren't doing it more affordable to people, but the opposite, unfortunately.
Besides all that, you are certainly going to find beers from all over the country here, and I guarantee you won't be disappointed with many of them. If you like belgian styles, your best bet is Wals (not from São Paulo, but widely available over here), nowadays probably the best brewery brewing belgian traditional styles in the country.
PS: Off course we are not USA. You won't find six-packs here, nor even a 12oz Imperial IPA bottle for 3 bucks. But, willing to spend some money and knowing what to go for and what not, it's possible to drink good beer.

Comment: Welcome! You need a blank line to make a paragraph break. I suggested an edit to this effect.

Answer (score 2):

I've been to Cervejeria Nacional, which makes some good brews: http://www.cervejarianacional.com.br/

I found this list of breweries in SP state, including SP city: http://beerme.com/region.php?411

While there might not be a ton of breweries in SP, craft beer bars can be found popping up all over.